# aspx page do not postback input type email data

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have one ASPX page(3.5) and i am trying to use HTML5 validation on it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AccountantEmail"  CssClass="form-control" type="email"  runat="server" required />
```

This control after rendering looks alright to me

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$AccountantEmail" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_AccountantEmail" class="form-control" type="email" required="">
```

Browser validations work well for email. When I try to submit the form I get required and format exceptions. However, the control has no data in the postback event.

It works if I remove the `type="email"` attribute.

Do I need to upgrade my .net version? or am I missing anything?

I am using Chrome 48, and all controls are in a Update Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it programatically:

```
AccountantEmail.Attributes["type"] = "email";
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. It worked well

Answer (score 0):

you should install .NET framework 4 that allows you to specify the type attribute.. Try this link to download.

[.NET FRAMEWORK 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2468871)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 3.5 `<asp:TextBox>` always render with type="text".

So instead of that just try

```
<input type="email" id="AccountantEmail" CssClass="form-control"/>
```